# Register directive for controls in App_Code with no namespace

Tags: directive

I know that if I created a custom control, say MyLabel in App_Code ..

```
namespace MyNamespace 
{
  public class MyLabel : Label { .. }
}
```

To access this control in my page, I would use this directive ..

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="foo" Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

If I did not provide a namespace (MyNamespace), how do I write the Register directive?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="foo" %>
```

(you might need a `tagName` value also.)

Comment: wow, it actually worked! thanks a lot! i can access MyLabel from the aspx page using the code you provided above. before, I was putting "MySite.App_Code" for the namespace and it does not work. anyway .. thanks marcc!

Comment: It is really a magic! I got "_When you develop a custom server control, you must include it in a namespace. If you do not, it will not be accessible from an ASP.NET page._ " from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) and thereafter believed I had to place my custom control in a namespace.